# Why $x(t)$ should be 1 in $(\frac{1}{2}, a_m]$ in proving the non convergence of the sequence in $C[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Here is the part of the book I am speaking about:

> [image]

> [image]

But I am wandering in the equalities before the last three lines, the one on the right, why  $x(t)$ should be 1 in $(\frac{1}{2}, a_m]$ in proving the non convergence of the sequence in $C[0,1]$? I know that $x_m$ is the line $m(t - \frac{1}{2})$ in this part of the interval.

Could anyone help me answer this question, please?

Comment: I think $x(t)$ is the limiting function?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But what does this mean?@Bey

Comment: See my answer below -- you should familiarize yourself with pointwise vs uniform convergence of a sequence of functions, as the above makes use of pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 1):

For every $s \in \left(\frac12, 1\right]$ there exists some natural $k$ such that $a_m \le s$ for $m \ge k$, that is $s$ definitely ends up with being an element of $[a_m, 1]$ as $m$ progresses. Now $$\underbrace{0 = \lim_{m \to +\infty} \int_{a_m}^1 \lvert 1-x(t) \rvert \mathrm d t}_{\text{as your book has proved}} \ge \int_s^1 \lvert 1-x(t) \rvert \mathrm d t \ge 0 .$$ Thus, if $x$ has to be a continuous function, then it has to be equal to $1$ on the interval $[s, 1]$, in particular $x(s) = 1$.

Comment: I still did not get the idea and I think you are not answering my question if I understood correctly, you maybe answering another question.

Comment: My problem is in the interval $[1/2, a_m]$ not $[a_m, 1]$

Comment: Re-reading your question, maybe I parsed the question incorrectly. Don't you understand why $x(t) = 1$  on $(\frac12, 1]$ --- and consequentely on its subset $(\frac12, a_m]$? Or something else?

Comment: I do not understand on $( \frac{1}{2}, a_m]$ why it is 1.